# Is this "trimming" of a supersolvable semimodular lattice known?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, order-theory, lattice-theory, posets

Let $L$ be a finite *(upper) semimodular* lattice. Recall that this means $L$ is graded and its rank function $\rho\colon L \to \mathbb{N}$ satisfies
$$ \rho(x) + \rho(y) \geq \rho(x\vee y)+\rho(x \wedge y)$$
for all $x,y \in L$. An element $x \in L$ is called *modular* if
$$ \rho(x) + \rho(y) = \rho(x\vee y)+\rho(x \wedge y)$$
for all $y \in L$. $L$ is *supersolvable* if it possesses a maximal chain $x_0 \lessdot x_1 \lessdot \cdots \lessdot x_n$ of modular elements.

Supersolvable lattices were introduced by Stanley in [this seminal paper](https://math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/11.pdf), cited below. (Stanley more generally defined supersolvability for any finite lattice $L$, not necessarily semimodular.) My question concerns a certain procedure for "trimming" a supersolvable semimodular lattice, to produce another one.

So now let $L$ be a supsersolvable semimodular lattice, with maximal chain of modular elements $x_0 \lessdot x_1 \lessdot \cdots \lessdot x_n$. Relative to this chain, we define $\mu\colon L \to \mathbb{N}$ by $\mu(x) := \min\{i\colon x \leq x_i \}$. And for any $k \geq 1$, we set
$$ L^{(k)} := \{x\in L\colon \mu(x) - \rho(x) < k \}.$$
For example $L^{(1)} = \{x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$, and $L^{(n)} = L$.

**Claim**: The subposet $L^{(k)}$ of $L$ is again a supersolvable semimodular lattice, with maximal chain of modular elements $x_0 \lessdot x_1 \lessdot \cdots \lessdot x_n$. (The rank of an element of $L^{(k)}$ is the same as its rank in $L$, and the join of two elements in $L^{(k)}$ is the same as their join in $L$, but meets may in general be different, so $L^{(k)}$ is not necessarily a sublattice of $L$.)

**Example**: Consider $L=B_3$, the rank $3$ finite Boolean lattice, with standard maximal chain $\varnothing \lessdot \{1\} \lessdot \{1,2\} \lessdot \{1,2,3\}$. Then $L^{(2)}$ is

[image]

which is indeed a supersolvable semimodular lattice.

The claim is not too difficult, but not completely trivial either. The hardest part is to show that $L^{(k)}$ remains graded, where you really have to use the modularity of the elements $x_0,\ldots,x_n$.

**Question**: Is this "trimming" construction for supersolvable semimodular lattices known?

It feels like the kind of thing which could have been studied before, especially in the context of matroid theory, but the literature there is pretty vast and I do not know exactly where to look. I need this construction for a paper I am writing, but I would much rather cite another paper than re-derive everything myself from scratch.

*Stanley, R. P.*, [**Supersolvable lattices**](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02945028), Algebra Univers. 2, 197-217 (1972). [ZBL0256.06002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0256.06002).

Comment: Nice construction! I guess I should think of $L^{(k)}$ as a "$k$-neighborhood" of the given modular chain?

Comment: @darijgrinberg: My mental image is the following. I imagine the distinguished modular chain as going straight up, and call the quantity $\mu(x) - \rho(x)$ the "slope" (relative to this vertical line) of $x$. The elements of the modular chain are the only elements of slope 0. And as we increase the slope of the elements we allow in $L^{(k)}$ we capture a bigger segment of the lattice.